# Android record video with options

Tags: android, video-capture

I want to record video with certain options. Like maximum duration, quality etc.
Is it possible to do that without custom implementation - just by calling intent?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
//add custom options here?
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_VIDEO);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code :

```
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 200);
```

For more options have a look at this :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Comment: It's a shame, that these options come only since API 8.